# Raid controller can't erase RAID config

Tags: raid, bios, raid-controller

I bought a Dell PowerEdge T320 that came with 2 1TB HDD and I just ordered 6 more used 3TB HDD. When setting up an array I'm able to see the original 2 HDD that came with the server but the 6 used drives are showing up as "foreign". I'm trying to erase the RAID configuration from those HDD's but I'm getting the following message

> One or more of your disks were secured using a different controller. This controller does not support security features. You need a controller with security to unlock a secured disks.

Would updating the BIOS add the "security features" needed to resolve this problem?

This is a server I bought for myself to learn and host some applications.

Comment: Dell seams to be lack on information here,
First try to only insert one of the drives and see if they can be cleared separately, otherwise do contact Dell if you don't get better answers here. The documentation I found is: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000137040/security-key-and-raid-management-for-dell-poweredge-h710-h710p-and-h810-raid-controllers

Some information suggests that you need the original controller/key to get them usable. Exactly what drives is it? Any model numbers?

Comment: Looks like Instant Secure Erase should get the drives going again. Of course the previous owner's data will be gone forever.